# How to make communication between xbap and javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, wpf, xbap

[image: Error image]Hi i have one xbap application and web application.  My xbap is hosted at scanner.aufait.in and web app is hosted at webapp.aufait.in. I have deployed xbap using clickonce and it is working. i am accessing it with iframe. I am trying to pass some data from xbap to javascript.

```
 private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             var filename="Passport";
             var hostScript BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.setTimeout("WorkDamnit()", 0);
             hostScript.document.ResponseData(filename);
        }
```

I have below javascript in my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.ResponseData = function (responseData) {
            window.opener.ResponseAlert(responseData);
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />  
    <title>ScannerView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://Scanner.aufytech.com/C3CKYC Scanner.xbap?

Param=@ViewBag.FileName" width="1000" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After button click event of xbap i want to return filename to html as below.

```
 window.ResponseAlert = function (responseData) {
  console.log(responseData);
}
```

When i click on xbap button i am getting error

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

I have attached screen shot of error. I am not able to figure where and why i am facing this error? Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.